# CSS syntax error in CodeSandBox when i try to write code in a brakets

Tags: javascript, css, visual-studio-code, syntax-error, codesandbox

In VSCode, there are no syntax error, but in CodeSandbox, there are always some syntax error. Why did it like that and how can i fix it? I'll be glad for any advice. Thank you in advance.

[This is the example of the code in CodeSandBox.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcOFi.jpg)

Comment: you are writing `scss` syntax in a `css` file

Comment: Change your file name extension if you are attempting to write SCSS.  This might help with your use of scss https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The people who commented above are right.
Make sure your file extension is `scss` instead of `css`.